# Explaining the optial behaviour of DVD reader lens

Tags: optics, experimental-physics, geometric-optics, home-experiment

Here is the lens removed from a DVD reader/writer's head
[image]
I do not have the dimension of the lens, neither could I find it online. Correct me if I am wrong, but I guess it is a plano-convex lens.

I placed this lens on top of a cellphone screen(with the flat side coinciding with the screen) and here is what I saw - a highly magnified image of the RGB pixels of the screen.

Here is a collage of screenshots from a video -
[image]

Optically, the object is placed very close to the lens. Then using the lens formula
$$
{1 \over v} - {1 \over u} = {1 \over f}
$$
we get $v = u$ for $u =0$. And by the magnification equation,
$$
M = -{v \over u}
$$
we get magnification as $1$ for $\lim {u \to 0}$. But we see a very large magnification. How to explain this optical behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, a few links will help. Here is a quick overview of [what lens design is](https://optics.synopsys.com/learn/learn-intro-optics-design.html). Here is an explanation of [how lenses work](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/geoopt/lenscon.html#c1). The second link has several useful links. Start with [magnification](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/geoopt/lensdet.html#c2). You can see that a large magnification requires light rays to be deflected by a large angle.

You are getting a large magnification because is this is a strong lens (short focal length). You can tell because the lens is strongly curved. The spherical side has a small radius. Large diameter lenses cannot be this strong.

There are various ways to calculate the focal length of a lens. The simplest is the thin lens approximation. It is for cases where the thickness of the lens is small compared to other lengths (weaker lenses). You cannot use it for this lens.

For a thick lens, you need to take the location of each surface into account when calculating focal length. The [thick lens formula](http://scienceworld.wolfram.com/physics/ThickLensFormula.html) is a better approximation.

For a thick lens, you can still use $1/v - 1/u = 1/f$. But you need to measure from the right locations, as shown [here](http://www.sjsu.edu/faculty/beyersdorf/Archive/Phys158F06/10-12%20Thick%20Lenses%20and%20the%20ABCD%20formalism.pdf).

So u is not 0. You would have to know the lens parameters to calculate it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the links. Huge appreciations for the links, especially regarding the thick lens formulation. Can you suggest me any easy ray tracing software to simulate the depicted observation with this lens? I am trying Oslo Edu version, which is taking quite some time to learn; and Optocad is really tough.

Comment: Sorry. I was last doing lens design around 1990. Kingslake was a great book. I see it is still sold and recommended. Keep in mind that the lens was designed for a very simple job: Focusing an on-axis monochromatic point of light onto an on-axis detector. Only spherical aberration is present. Other aberrations are not. Use of a non-optimal plano-convex shape shows that spherical aberration isn't important. I designed lenses like that with a pocket calculator. Software is for more complex jobs. It will help you choose glasses, curvatures, and spacing to minimize aberrations.

Comment: I take some of that back. From the picture, the lens does not look spherical. These days, lenses are cast from plastic, not polished. Non spherical shapes are much easier now. That means the lens was designed to minimize spherical aberration. If you knew more about the lens shape, you could still use hand methods to calculate focal length. Focal length is for paraxial rays, very close to the center of the lens, where the asphere is very close to spherical. Aberrations tell you how badly other rays fail to meet the paraxial rays. Without details of the shape, software won't help.